# Evaluating Groups Based on Multiple Variables

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, group-differences

I have what seems like a simple question, but I've been trying to find a solution all afternoon with no luck.

My dataset that includes a number of continuous variables, and two different grouping variables. For a reproducible example, we can use the `mtcars` dataset in `R`:

```
# example data
df <- mtcars

# grouping variables
unique(df$gear)  # groups are 3, 4, 5
unique(df$cyl)   # groups are 4, 6, 8

# continuous variables
summary(df[,c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec")])
```

My question is: **does grouping the data by `gear` or `cyl` minimize the total within-class variability of the continuous variables?** Or, in other words, which is a 'better' grouping variable?

For example, using kmeans we can classify the data into 3 groups and extract the total sum of squares and the sum of squares for each clusters:

```
# cluster with kmeans
fit <- kmeans(df[,c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec")], 3)

# total sum of squares
fit$totss     # 623175.2

# within-cluster sum of squares for each cluster
fit$withinss  # 46627.54 11834.09 32780.12
```

What I am trying to get, is the equivalent of `fit$totss` and `fit$withinss`, but using `gear` and `cyl` as predefined clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Total variance is commutative, as it is a sum of sums.

It's very easy to compute on your own. You can just do it one variable at a time. So there is nothing particularly challenging to group the data by one variable, then compute the variances of each group.

It is to be expected that the grouping with the more even size distribution usually yields the better reduction.

However, total variance is not meaningful when the variables have different scale. So the result will be questionable.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse. I understand regarding the variables with different scales - with my real data, everything is normalized to a common scale first. However I'm not sure what you mean by commutative. I have added more detail to the question. My understanding of commutative would be that `sum(df[,c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec")]^2)` would be equal to `fit$totss`, but this does not appear to be the case. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Only if the overall mean is 0.